# How to update replicated Docker service

Tags: django, docker

I'm still learning Docker, and unfortunately, after hours of reading its docs and trying various approaches, I need to ask for help here.

I have 3 Droplets on Digital Ocean - dev, staging and production. They host a Django application and a database.

Both dev and staging have one container, which is simply a Python container, and one MySQL container.
I update them by pulling changes from a Bitbucket repository, applying migrations using
`docker exec -ti CONTAINER /bin/bash`
and restarting the Python container.

The production Droplet has a replicated service and the image pulled from the container registry on Digital Ocean.
I pull changes from the repository on Bitbucket, but because I can't simply restart the container, the changes are not reflected on the website.

I tried `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml SERVICE --with-registry-auth` and `docker service update --image IMAGE SERVICE`, but no effect.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a new image through Bitbucket. Then `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml SERVICE --with-registry-auth` pulled the new image from the repository on Digital Ocean and reflected the changes on the website.

Answer (score 0):

As you previously mentioned you can do that using the docker CLI, but if you are new to docker you might want to try out https://www.portainer.io/ which will help you perform such tasks more easily. Also portainer adds another API lever to docker, which is also nice.